# Memory management issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have allocated object inside the function [Method.]

inside parser method.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    Information *aInfo = [[Information alloc] init];

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]){

        aInfo.strStoreId = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"storeid"];
        [arrayList addObject:aInfo];
    } else if ([ActionType isEqualToString:@"action"]) {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
            aInfo.strStoreId = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"storeid"];
           [arrayList addObject:aInfo];
        }

    }
}
```

How do I manage the memory issue in this case?

Comment: It's not really very clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[aInfo release];` or `[aInfo autorelease];` at the end of the method

Answer (score 2):

You can just release the object, adding it to the array increased the retain count.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    Information *aInfo = [[Information alloc] init];

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]){

        aInfo.strStoreId = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"storeid"];
        [arrayList addObject:aInfo];
    } else if ([ActionType isEqualToString:@"action"]) {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
            aInfo.strStoreId = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"storeid"];
           [arrayList addObject:aInfo];
        }

    }

    [aInfo release], aInfo = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have the possibility to define the `aInfo` variable as a class variable and release it in the following method:

```
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
```